# Overstaying In Schengen area for about 2 years without knowing

Tags: resident-permit

I went to Sweden in early 2014 to visit a friend. I was 18 y/o and, due to problems back home, I ended up staying there for a year. I then left in late 2015 without any problems. I went back to visit again in 2015, was allowed in without any problems, and stayed another year leaving in 2016 without any problems. What i didn't know was that I could only stay there for 3 months on my passport. Since I never got in trouble or anything, I didn't think it was an issue. It's only now when I'm thinking about getting a work permit over there that I came to realize that I need a resident permit.

So I'm wondering what might happen if I apply for the resident permit since they need to see the stamps on my passport?

Comment: It depends on the country.  Where are you thinking of applying for a work and residence permit?

Comment: Do you have a job offer? You can't apply for a work permit otherwise.

Comment: How did you support yourself for those extended stays?

Answer (score 4):

They might see that you overstayed your visa twice previously, interpret that to mean that you have an obvious disregard for their immigration laws, and deny you your visa. That's pretty much the worst case scenario. They might completely disregard your previous overstays, especially as it appears that you have left on your cognizance, and grant you the visa. That's pretty much the best case scenario. There aren't a whole of in-betweens.

If you are asking what they *will* do, you may just have to apply and find out. Since you never seem to have entered their overstay system, it may be that it only affects such things as long term resident permit applications or citizenship applications where they are likely to dig deeper. A quick google of cases similar to yours, in country and basic situation, look like they've worked out in favor of the immigrant as long as there was a high degree of complete honesty. Consider getting a Swedish immigration attorney to handle this matter for you. You chances improve vastly if you do.